# puppet agent .conf file missing on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: puppet, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed  **puppet agent 3.4*** on ubuntu 14.04 via Synaptic Manager.

While configuring puppet, I did not find `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` file. 
Is there any different setup on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 1):

According to puppet [documentation:](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/dirs_confdir.html#location)

> The location of Puppet’s confdir is somewhat complex. The short version is that it’s usually at one of the following locations:
>
> /etc/puppetlabs/puppet
>
> /etc/puppet
>
> C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\puppet\etc
>
> The actual default confdir depends on your user account, OS version, and Puppet distribution (Puppet Enterprise vs. open source). See the table for your operating system below to locate your actual confdir. For details on system vs. user confdir behavior, see

Answer (score 1):

You can simply find out where Puppet looks for its configuration:

```
puppet agent --configprint config
```

In Puppet 3, this uses different defaults when you are `root` than for unpriviliged users. You should generally be `root` when invoking Puppet.